# How can i open a MSAcess Database in win7 64 bit OS using CPP?

Tags: c++, ms-access, 64-bit, database-connection

All i need to do is to open the MSAcess DB in 64 bit operating system.My code works fine in 32 bit operating sytems but when ported to 64 bit ,the open function throws an exception "Database operation Failed".My code part is as follows

```
//Code
CDatabase* m_pDatabase;
m_pDatabase = new CDatabase();
string szConnect = Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=E:\Application Files\Database\PLConfig.mdb
m_pDatabase->OpenEx(szConnect.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jet (.mdb) driver is not for 64 bit, you need the ACE drivers for 2010 and a suitable connections string ( http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007/ )

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}
```

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: thank you Remou.That was really helpful.But the thing is i coudn't find a exact solution for my issue.However i installed the Accdb_64Bit and i could connect to access DB by creating a system DSN.But the call still fails if i use DSN less connection string.Now my Connection string looks like this `code` "Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=E:\Application Files\Database\MyDatabase.mdb"

Comment: The exception i receive is "CDBException * __ptr64 at memory location 0x00129ed8.."

Comment: I am afraid you have run past my ability to help. It may be worth posting a new question now the more obvious problem of the wrong drivers for x64 is covered.

Comment: If you do EXACTLY what it says to do at the linked website IT WILL work.  If you don't use the ACE drivers, then it won't work, at least not with a 64-bit process.